# PHP version differs on different folders on same server

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.2, php-5.4

I had installed and maintained an application with two different environments, in testing PHP version works fine. but, in clone ( as production ) it looks lower version.

tried to set overall account version into PHP 7.1^ but it doesn't work for me.

Version Difference(1) :

[image: version difference]

Server Settings(2):

[image: server settings]

Comment: Is one of them a virtual machine?

Comment: Too little information here.  I'd consult your host.

Comment: Looks like the your web server is configured to use the new version of PHP and in the terminal, the default "cli" version of PHP is probably linked to the old version.

Comment: @Latheesan not immediately obvious but version appears to be switched according to the directory where Php is called from.  I'm sure the host has instructions for how this configuration works.  Php versions are freshly built.